# Reformatting array into dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains ten years (3653 days of temperatures) for 307 global locations. The data is set up as an array (example below) containing 3653 data values (temperatures) for 307 longitudes and 307 latitudes.

```
my.array = array(1:344291597, dim=c(307, 307, 3653))
```

I want to produce a `data.frame` that contains the 3653 days of temperature values along the columns, with coordinates along the rows in two columns. For example:

```
Lon     Lat     01/01/1971     02/01/1971     03/01/1971     04/01/1971
20.5    60.5    -6.5           -7.1           -5.9           -6.3
20.5    61.5    -6.4           -7.2           -6.8           -6.5
20.5    62.5    -7.7           -7.9           -7.3           -7.4
```

Is there a solution for this? I have tried various approaches with no success.

Comment: Do you need `matrix(my.array, nrow = 307, ncol = 3653)` ?

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah but this doesn't deliver the required result.  I need the dataframe to contain 3653 columns for the 307 longitudes and latitudes in the data array.

Comment: Actually, its not clear to me what your expected output is. `my.array` has some different numbers than what you have in your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
my.array = array(1:344291597, dim=c(307, 307, 3653))
#Find locations from array
Locations <- cbind(my.array[,1,1],my.array[1,,1])
#Create new matrix to store temperature values
LocationsData <- matrix(data= NA,nrow = dim(my.array)[1], ncol = dim(my.array)[3])
#Populate new matrix with temperature values 
for (i in 1:dim(my.array)[1]){

    LocationsData[i,] <-as.vector(t(my.array[i,i,]))
}

Desiredoutput <- data.frame(cbind(Locations,LocationsData))
#add correct names
Names(Desiredoutput) <- c("Lon", "Lat", dimnames(my.array)[[3]])
```